# Unable to configure and run pithos.io using AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-s3, embedded-jetty

I am trying to configure pithos.io on my server testmbr1.kabuter.com:8081:

Here is how I start pithos.io:

```
java -jar pithos-0.7.5-standalone.jar -f pithos.yaml
```

My pithos.yaml:

```
service:
  host: "0.0.0.0"
  port: 8081
logging:
  level: info
  console: true
  overrides:
    io.pithos: debug
options:
  service-uri: testmbr1.kabuter.com
  default-region: myregion
keystore:
  keys:
    AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:
      master: true
      tenant: test@example.com
      secret: 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
bucketstore:
  default-region: myregion
  cluster: "45.33.37.148"
  keyspace: storage
regions:
  myregion:
    metastore:
      cluster: "45.33.37.148"
      keyspace: storage
    storage-classes:
      standard:
        cluster: "45.33.37.148"
        keyspace: storage
        max-chunk: "128k"
        max-block-chunk: 1024
cassandra:
   saved_caches_directory: "target/db/saved_caches"
   data_file_directories:
     - "target/db/data"
   commitlog_directory: "target/db/commitlog"
```

I am using AWS Java SDK to connect. Below is my JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testPithosIO() {
try {
    ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
    config.setSignerOverride("S3SignerType");

    EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("http://testmbr1.kabuter.com:8081",
            "myregion");
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
            "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY");
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion("myregion")
            .withClientConfiguration(config)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration).build();
    s3Client.createBucket("mybucket1");
    System.out.println(s3Client.getRegionName());
    System.out.println(s3Client.listBuckets());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

My problems is 1) I am getting: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to mybucket1.testmbr1.kabuter.com:8081 [mybucket1.testmbr1.kabuter.com/198.105.254.130, mybucket1.testmbr1.kabuter.com/104.239.207.44] failed: connect timed out

> This was fixed by adding mybucket1.testmbr1 CNAME record pointing to testmbr1.kabuter.com.

2) while trying to createBucket: s3Client.createBucket("mybucket1") I am getting:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: d98b7908-d11e-458a-be27-254b136f344a), S3 Extended Request ID: d98b7908-d11e-458a-be27-254b136f344a
```

How do I get it to working? pithos.io seems to have limited documentation.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my endpoint was using a non-standard port:

```
http://testmbr1.kabuter.com:8081
```

I had to define server-uri in pithos.yaml with the port as well:

```
server-uri : testmbr1.kabuter.com:8081
```